# Find #pages in website

Tags: google-analytics, web-scraping

I'm collecting data on complexities of several domains- represented by total pages, visited and unvisited.

I was initially finding what I wanted from Google Analytics by drilling down to `Behavior -> Site Content -> Landing Pages` but wasn't sure if that was returning unvisited sites. Then I tried `All Pages` per domain, but that returned like 1,800 results for "pages", with params in some cases `/Pages/Results.aspx?k=update`.

That being said, I don't think I can rely on GA for total pages per site.

Then I thought about using a web scraper, namely web2disk or httrack.com, to scrape for the #pages per domain. Is that a good path to take? Is it necessary to get this information?

Thanks

Comment: landing pages are different than all pages. Look up the meaning on Google! You should also be looking at pageviews not visits when you analyzing landing pages. 

You can also scrape your site and find every URL, but what is the point of that if you don't know how many people viewed it, how long they stayed, etc...

Comment: only you can answer whether or not that info is useful to you. Ask yourself, what business decision(s) can/will you make with that knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how many pages there are on your site you need to crawl your site to find all the pages. Because of the way it works Google analytics will 100% only show you data on pages which have been loaded (which fires the analytics code) in a browser.

http://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/ is a paid for crawler you can use to find all the pages (£99), or you could potentially try to hack something together using a free crawler like http://import.io (disclaimer: I work at import.io) to get all the URls.

**Find all visited pages via GA:**
Behaviour -> Site Content -> Landing Pages does not give you any pages which were not 'Landed upon'.

> Then I tried All Pages per domain, but that returned like 1,800 results for "pages", with params in some cases /Pages/Results.aspx?k=update.

To remove the params from the page URls you can use a report filter at the top right of the table. Click 'advanced', and use the tools there to exclude params from URls.

Alternatively you can switch your primary dimension to 'Page title' if you have Unique page titles for each page (and identical ones for pages with params).

Comment: Where do you switch your primary dimension?

Comment: if you are looking at a table of data, it is above the table on the  left. do a find (ctrl f) for "Primary Dimension" and it will highlight it for you.